# Python: Use value from file a to search for lines in another file

Tags: python, file, search

Newbie question

I have 2 files 
   File A: File with a list of items (apple, pears, oranges)
   File B: File with all fruit in the world (1,000,000 lines)

In unix I would grep apple from file B and return all results

In unix I would
    1. grep apple from file b >> fruitfound.txt
    2. grep pears from file b >> fruitfound.txt
    3. grep oranges from file b >> fruitfound.txt

I want to a python script that uses values from file a and search file b and then writes out the output. NOTE: FILE B would have green apple, red apple, yellow apple and I would want to write all 3 results to the fruitfound.txt

Kindest Regards

Kornity

Comment: Dear user, welcome to SO. Explain what have you tried already and what the problem is and we will do our best to help you.

Comment: You can combine grep commands into a single one: `grep -f a b > fruitfound.txt`

Answer (score 1):

`grep -f $patterns $filename` does exactly that. No need to use a python script.

Answer (score 0):

To find lines that contain any of given keywords in Python, you could use a regex:

```
import re
from itertools import ifilter

def fgrep(words, lines):
    # note: allow a partial match e.g., 'b c' matches 'ab cd'
    return ifilter(re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, words))).search, lines)
```

To turn it into a command-line script:

```
import sys

def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as kwfile: # read keywords from given file
        # one keyword per line
        keywords = [line.strip() for line in kwfile if line.strip()]

    if not keywords:
       sys.exit("no keywords are given")

    if len(sys.argv) > 2: # read lines to match from given file
        with open(sys.argv[2]) as file:
            sys.stdout.writelines(fgrep(keywords, file))
    else: # read lines from stdin
        sys.stdout.writelines(fgrep(keywords, sys.stdin))

main()
```

Example:

```
$ python fgrep.py a b > fruitfound.txt
```

There are more efficient algorithms e.g., [Ago-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm), but it takes less than a second to filter millions lines on my machine and it might be good enough (`grep` is several times faster). Surprisingly [`acora`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/acora/) that is based on Ago-Corasick algorithm is slower for the data I've tried.